# How to merge and update Json doc in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a scenario where i have to json docs which come from my back end, one is the grid definition, the other is a grid custom file for user. in my case a user can have modifications but does not.

Certain elements have default values which user can over write and others are optional. in my doc all data is stored in a columns doc array and each column has a unique id.

How can i go and use the grid_info column as a base, then if the user_grid_info has column keys overwrite with user values for that key as well ass add key/values not set in the grid_info and output a combined columns array

```
{
        "id" :"D0842C42-D43F-426D-A12E-D0141FE58337",
        "_type" : "grid_info",

        "columns" :[
                {
                    "colId": "A3C031BA-C157-42D8-8208-9019B8B87061",
                    "headerName":"ID",
                    "field": "id",
                    "width" : 100,
                    "sortable": false               
                },
                {
                    "colId": "671B1BAA-2D2E-419D-9C74-182D9E87A502",
                    "headerName":"Name",
                    "field": "name",
                    "width" : 150,
                    "sortable": true                
                },
                {
                    "colId": "CCB26780-6474-4606-B9EA-750F80354599",
                    "headerName":"Zip Code",
                    "field": "zip",
                    "width" : 75,
                    "sortable": true                
                }


        ]
    }


    {
        "id" :"A40D39F1-0849-4C68-A506-6EC89DBD7163",
        "_type" : "user_grid_info",
        "grid_key" : "grid_info::D0842C42-D43F-426D-A12E-D0141FE58337",
        "user_id" : "3D10D638-39E1-40CD-A3A5-2B0D9AB51F1F",


        "columns" :[
                {
                    "colId": "A3C031BA-C157-42D8-8208-9019B8B87061",
                    "hide" : true,

                },
                {
                    "colId": "671B1BAA-2D2E-419D-9C74-182D9E87A502",
                    "position":1,

                    "width" : 200               
                },
                {
                    "colId": "CCB26780-6474-4606-B9EA-750F80354599",
                    "headerName":"Zip Code +4",
                    "position":2,
                    "width" : 100           
                }


        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the objects just in one in the moment to use the configurations in grid, something like:

```
let defaultConfiguration = { // your object from json with grid_info values }
let userConfiguration = { //your object from json with user grid info values }
```

so just create a merge variable

let merge = {...defaultConfiguration, ...userConfiguration }

the result is the all values of defaultConfiguration with all values different of userConfiguration.

Comment: Ok, tried the basic merge and it does only return the key values from second doc. I was able to create somewhat of a merged doc by using the lodash _merge function which looked promising but after some more testing is not reliable, It does not use a key to merge document but index so if i have an array of 3 docs in each document it will merge 1 with 1, 2 with 2 and so on. In my case i need to merge based on key of colId in the array

Comment: In this case, you always need find by key and just after merge just the each column generating a new object, it a specific code in my opinion. You already tried in this way ?